# Angular Elements with Router

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-elements

I want to develop web-component based on angular elements, which will be integrated into non-angular application. Is there any proper way for this web-component to use routing?

I need it because web-component will contain views for creating/viewing list/viewing details/viewing settings of some entity (article).

This routing, as I see it, should not affect primary routing of main application. I was thinking about creating it based on names router outlets, but it involves adding some dirty hack fixes.

Comment: What problem are you facing with that?

Comment: Well, if we are talking about router outlets - it throws an error for unmatch url segment after first navigation. In this article you can find a fix for that issue :https://medium.com/@timon.grassl/how-to-use-routing-in-angular-web-components-c6a76449cdb, but it's working only when you use web-component in a scope of other angular application.

Comment: To be specific, I'm looking for a proper example of creating routing for web-component in a scope of non-angular application.\

Comment: so you want a complete component which is using router-outlet in it and you want to export that component as webcomponent.Correct?

Comment: Yeah. Plus it should work in non-angular app, don't affect primary app routing.

Comment: Primary app wont be affected at all as for publishing web-component you need to create another module and bootstrap them separately so it wont affect your main application.

Comment: well, it does not work this way for me. can you create some example, please?

Comment: what does not work web-component or your main application?

Comment: anyone found a solution for this?